# Change <tr> (values from php while loop) background with javascript when cell has some values

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm new on programming, also sorry my English.

I'm making a Dynamic Website for my office, and I'm having some trouble with a javascript function.

I have this table with modals and other links, where values are echoed from a while loop. Everything is working perfectly, but I need to implement this function.

Here's my html/php while loop

```
<?php

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    { ?>
    <tr id="lavorazione"> 
    <td><? echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['carrier']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['tt']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['apertura']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['cliente']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['linea']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['risorsa']; ?></td>
    <td id="escalation"><? echo $row['escalation']; ?></td>

    <td> <!-- Colonna dei modali -->

    <form method="post">
```

Some other code...

```
    </td> <!-- Chiudo la casella dei modali-->



</tr> <!-- Chiudo la riga della tabella -->
```

The td id="escalation">. For example if $row['escalation'] is I level the background of the tr has to be #FF8080

Can someone please help me? I'm blocked on this since two days at the moment!

Comment: Do you want to style the `escalation` td based on if the value exists, or style the tr? Your question isn't too clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
    <tr class="color_<?php $row[escalation]?>">
<td><? echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['carrier']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['tt']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['apertura']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['cliente']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['linea']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['risorsa']; ?></td>
    <td id="escalation"><? echo $row['escalation']; ?></td>

</tr>
```

then use some css like

```
 mod_1{background-color:#FF8080}
```

Comment: what is `mod_1` supposed to represent?

Comment: I used the Jame's method, but thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr id="lavorazione">
<td><? echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
```

becomes

```
<tr id="lavorazione"<?php
if ($row['escalation'] == 'something') {
  echo ' class="red"';
}
?>>
<td><? echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
```

And then you have in your css:

```
.red { background-color: #FF8080 }
```